# Grid Binding Error in Kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ViewBag.ScoringList as a list of elements like:

```
Scoring_id=1, Code=2,Correlated_To="correlationtext1"

Scoring_id=2, Code=3,Correlated_To="correlationtext2"
```

I want to bind it in kendo grid.

I have done as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(ViewBag.ScoringList)
                            .Name("lvScoring")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                             {
                                // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
                                 columns.Bound(correlatedTo => ViewBag.ScoringList.Correlated_To);

                              })

                            )
```

But its giving me error on `columns =>` that:

```
Can not use lamda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation...
```

How can i bind grid???

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(ViewBag.ScoringList)
                            .Name("lvScoring")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                             {
                                 columns.Bound(Correlated_To).Title("Correlated To");;

                              })

                            )
```

Comment: try this  `columns.Bound(p=> p.Correlated_To);` or `columns.Bound(Correlated_To);`

Comment: did that work for you?

because on the Right hand side of `=>` operator comes an expression or statement.